# Google Appmaker - Search people by PrimaryOrganizationTitle in the PeopleViewer template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm working on the peopleViewer template, and I'd like to know how to modify the search option to look for people by post as well as by name.

I've tried adding:
`userInfoDs.query.filters.PrimaryOrganizationTitle = title;`in the loadAllData() function, but

1- The auto-completion doesn't show PrimaryOrganizationTitle in the filters
2- I dont think `var title = userInfoDs.query.parameters.PrimaryOrganizationTitle;` will work to create the variable.

Edit: Alternatively, I'd like to know if it's possible to manually add a filter to be used in `userInfoDs.query.filters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasource `userInfoDs` you are referring is used to load data about found/selected/current user (`People` page). `SearchResults` page uses `SearchResults` datasource. Search box in the page header is bound to [keywords](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#keywords). Directory Model's `keywords` would look for search term occurrences in First/Last Names and Primary Email. Directory Model doesn't support filtering by `PrimaryOrganizationTitle`: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory#user_fields_and_query_operators

So, if you desperately want to search people by fields that are not supported by Directory Model out of the box, you have no other way but using [Admin Directory SDK](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory). Here is approximate taste of your server side search script.

```javascript
/**
 * Searches for people.
 */
function search(term) {
  var result = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: 'ENTER HERE YOUR DOMAIN (exapmle.com)',
    // Build your query basing on this doc
    // https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users
    query: getQuery(term),
    viewType: 'domain_public',
    maxResults: 10
  });

  return mapToAppMakerRecords(result);
}
```

Here `getQuery` function should build query similar to `email:Bob or name:Bob or orgTitle:Bob`, and `mapToAppMakerRecords` should transform search results to the form that App Maker's UI can digest ([Calculated Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) or a follow up query to [Directory Model](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/directory)). With this approach all work related to results sorting and paging will fall on your shoulders as well.